# Changing (reducing) the quality of an ogg file?

Tags: ffmpeg, convert, conversion, ogg-vorbis

I have an .ogg file (containing speech) with 192kbps quality that i'd like to reduce to 32kbps (to save space)

How can i do this?

---

So far i've tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.ogg -ab 32k -f ogg new-filename.ogg
```

But i get this error:

```
[libvorbis @ 0x56157365ab60] encoder setup failed
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Am i using the wrong command? Is there a better approach i can take to save space? Please note that i only have access to the 192kbps file (not the original)

Grateful for help!

Comment: The error message indicates you have the encoding parameters wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two excellent choices here:

1. Adjust your FFmpeg command line to produce a smaller Ogg Vorbis file
2. Use FFmpeg to create a small file using libopus

Details of both are below:

**1. Adjust your FFmpeg command line...**

The key issue is that FFmpeg will not *automagically* change the audio sampling rate to appropriately match your selected bitrate. But then FFmpeg usually does not do a lot of hand holding I guess!

Bear in mind that an Audio CD will normally have a sampling rate of 44100 Hz while simple telephony would normally have a sampling rate of slightly greater than 8000 Hz. So you have a choice to make for the best sampling rate for your 32k Ogg Vorbis audio. The following are some guidelines:

- **44100 Hz**: Typical Audio CD sample rate. *Rejected by FFmpeg for a 32k file.*
- **32000 Hz**: Adequate for speech and also adequate for other audio files where a smaller file size is required with an expected small loss of quality. *Rejected by FFmpeg for a 32k file.*
- **22050 Hz**: Adequate for speech and usable for other audio with the expectation that there will be audio quality loss. *Accepted by FFmpeg for a 32k file.*
- **11025 Hz**: Very poor sound quality. *Accepted by FFmpeg for a 32k file.*
- **8000 Hz**: Slightly lower sampling rate than a modern telephony system, not recommended for most recording tasks. *Accepted by FFmpeg for a 32k file.*

With this in mind my own testing suggests that you would be best to use a sampling rate of 22050 Hz, note that this should be *perfectly adequate* for speech, and thus your command line should be:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.ogg -c:a libvorbis -ab 32k -ar 22050 new-filename.ogg
```

And this produced a quite reasonable outcome on my own setup...

**2. Use FFmpeg to create a small file using libopus...**

If you are perhaps not all that set on using Ogg Vorbis an excellent alternative is to use Opus, which in my tests shaved a reasonable number of kilobytes off each file in comparison to the Ogg Vorbis 32k encode. Try something like the following which has been tailored for your speech files:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.ogg \
-c:a libopus -b:a 16k -ar 16000 -ac 1 -application voip \
new-filename.ogg
```

You will be pleasantly surprised by both the resulting output file size and audio quality. I have included a link to a great HydrogenAudio resource in the 'References' which should guide to an even better command line for Opus...

**References:**

- [Sample Rates](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/sample_rates.html): A nice page from the Audacity developers that demonstrates the best settings for audio sample rates.
- [Speech encoding quality](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Opus#Speech_encoding_quality): The definitive HydrogenAudio page to guide Opus settings for speech.
- [15.8 libopus](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libopus-1): FFmpeg options for use with libopus encoding. Note the `-application voip` setting that I used above and which does not have an equivalent with opusenc (unlike the other settings).

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using opus like this: `ffmpeg -i filename.ogg -c:a libopus -ar 16k -ac 1 -b:a 16k -vbr on -compression_level 10 new_filename.ogg`

Comment: @sunyata `-compression_level 10` is the default for this encoder so you can remove that.

Comment: i independently got to the same conclusion with `opus`... bitrate 16k is amazingly good and small (10%)! but i got an issue with album art... any idea how to get same compression using `opusenc`? or any other ideas for the simplest library reduction with this 10% in mind? https://superuser.com/questions/1648830/reduce-my-90gb-collection-of-mp3-to-about-10gb

Answer (score 1):

This low bitrate is not supported with the default sampling rate of the file. You must specify a lower sampling rate before you can lower the bitrate. Add the option -ar 8000 for your option -b:a 32k to be accepted.